# Incorrect Result of Total Download's Code

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I use the following code to display the total download and upload. The problem arises when the cumulative download exceeds 2 GB, the result being the number of bits:

```
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  Downloaded, Uploaded:integer;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Downloaded < 1024 then
  Recv.Caption           := FormatFloat(' + Recv: #,0 Bit',Downloaded)
  else if (Downloaded > 1024) and (Downloaded < 1048576) then
  Recv.Caption           := FormatFloat(' + Recv: #,##0.00 Kb',Downloaded/1024)
  else if (Downloaded > 1048576) and (Downloaded < 1073741824) then
  Recv.Caption           := FormatFloat(' + Recv: #,##0.00 Mb',Downloaded/1048576)
  else if (Downloaded > 1073741824) then
  Recv.Caption           := FormatFloat(' + Recv: #,##0.00 Gb', Downloaded/1073741824);

  if Uploaded < 1024 then
  Sent.Caption               := FormatFloat(' + Sent: #,0 Bit',Uploaded)
  else if (Uploaded > 1024) and (Uploaded < 1048576) then
  Sent.Caption               := FormatFloat(' + Sent: #,##0.00 Kb',Uploaded/1024)
  else if (Uploaded > 1048576) and (Uploaded < 1073741824) then
  Sent.Caption               := FormatFloat(' + Sent: #,##0.00 Mb',Uploaded/1048576)
  else if (Uploaded > 1073741824) then
  Sent.Caption               := FormatFloat(' + Sent: #,##0.00 Gb', Uploaded/1073741824);
end;
```

Can anyone explain why it is returning the incorrect result and more importantly, how to fix it so it returns the correct result ? Thank you so much...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An `Integer` cannot hold a value greater than 2GB (`MaxInt` is 2147483647, which is ~1.99 GB).  If you try to exceed that, it overflows and becomes negative.  You need to use `Int64` instead.

Also, you should be using `B` or `Bytes` instead of `Bit`.  You are not downloading bits, you are downloading bytes.

Try this:

```
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  Downloaded, Uploaded: Int64;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function FormatBytes(ABytes: Int64): string;
begin
  if ABytes < 1024 then
    Result := FormatFloat('#,0 B', ABytes)
  else if ABytes < 1048576 then
    Result := FormatFloat('#,##0.00 Kb', ABytes / 1024)
  else if ABytes < 1073741824 then
    Result := FormatFloat('#,##0.00 Mb', ABytes / 1048576)
  else if ABytes < 1099511627776 then
    Result := FormatFloat('#,##0.00 Gb', ABytes / 1073741824)
  else
    Result := FormatFloat('#,##0.00 Tb', ABytes / 1099511627776);
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Recv.Caption := ' + Recv: ' + FormatBytes(Downloaded);
  Send.Caption := ' + Sent: ' + FormatBytes(Uploaded);
end;
```

Comment: Sir Remy, thank you so much. I have compiled it successfully. Now, I'm trying to download some GBs files. Btw, your code contains more than one semicolon at `Result := FormatFloat('#,##0.00 Gb', ABytes / 1073741824);` that cause error when compiling my app.

Comment: I removed the offending semicolon.

Comment: Sir Remy, i am sorry but the result does not work correctly. When the cumulative download exceeds 1 GB, the result being **0.00 Tb**. Can you fix it please ? Thank you so much!

Comment: @Johan BTW `1 shl 10`, `1 shl 20`, `1 shl 30`, `1 shl 40` much more readable then `1024`, `1048576`, `1073741824`, `1099511627776`

Comment: @Abelisto and slightly faster. :)

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez Not sure that it is faster because constant expressions calculates at compile time. It is just the simple way to avoid mistyping. @RemyLebeau While download amount can not be negative that `UInt64` is more appropriate.

Comment: @Abelisto You are right. IMHO what you may be able to do is use plain integer math. Something like http://paste.ee/p/WF5sb as we embedded within our SynCommons.pas unit.

Comment: @Abelisto: technically yes, a `UInt64` might make more sense. On the other hand, an `Int64` can hold a value up to *7 EXABYTES*.  It is unlikely that an app will ever reach that value, unless it is tracking uploads/downloads over a period of many many many years (and even then it probably won't reach past the PETABYTE layer, considering that most storage systems are still measured in GIGABYTES and TERABYTES).

Comment: @RemyLebeau I told not about size but about logic. Niklaus Wirth designed Pascal as hard-typed language not for nothing :) So anybody have be informed that this parameter can not hold negative value. Good luck.